# Safari Push Notifications authenticationToken

Tags: safari, push-уведомления, authenticationtoken

Нужно сделать Safari Push Notifications.

Использовал эти гайды:

https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/safari-push-notifications-ec171bdf6ead

http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/how-to-implement-safari-push-notifications-on-your-website/

и

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html

Не понимаю одного. Где мне взять `authenticationToken` для `website.json`?

Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: authenticationToken - это специальная строка, которая позволяем вам лично идентифицировать пользователья. для тестирования можно для себя туда любую строку передать размером 16 символов и более

Answer (score 1, accepted):

authenticationToken - это специальная строка, которая позволяем вам лично идентифицировать пользователья. для тестирования можно для себя туда любую строку передать размером в 16 символов и более